# ActionbarSherlock want to insert an image inbetween icon and Tabs

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a tablet layout using ABS.

The Home (app) icon is displayed and my 4 tabs are shown to the right of it.

I'd like to insert an image (for advertising) inbetween the icon and tabs.

Does anybody know if it can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the log trace or some code which you think is responsible for the error

Comment: Thanks Orlymee, There is no error occuring actually, I rephrased the title...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert an image between the icon and the tabs, but you could:

A. Use a logo drawable which has the icon and ad in it -- then add this by setting the `android:logo` attribute on your application or activity to your logo drawable.

or

B. Use a custom view and set this on the ActionBar with `setCustomView(View view)`.

Comment: Thanks joseph, I'll look into the customview approach.